# IllegalStateException in PullToRefreshListView$InternalListViewSDK9

Tags: java, android, illegalstateexception, pull-to-refresh

I'm using PullToRefresh library in two activities of my application. I know, this library is deprecated, but it very useful and it can handle refresh genstures not only from top but also bottom. But it have a problem: rarely application crash with this log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread. [in ListView(16908298, class com.handmark.pulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshListView$InternalListViewSDK9) with Adapter(class android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter)]
 at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1551)
 at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:4218)
 at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7461)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2264)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:1995)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2270)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2010)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2182)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1512)
 at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2466)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2130)
 at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7641)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3682)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3613)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4804)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4783)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4875)
 at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
 at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
 at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:174)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:4854)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4894)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:530)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This crash occur so rarely, that I see it on my device only one time in months of frequent usage. But I see crash reports with this log from users in Google Play Developer Console.

As far as I understand it, this crash occuring not in my code, this occuring in code of PullToRefresh library in InternalListViewSDK9 class. Here is code of InternalListViewSDK9:

```
@TargetApi(9)
final class InternalListViewSDK9 extends InternalListView {

    public InternalListViewSDK9(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean overScrollBy(int deltaX, int deltaY, int scrollX, int scrollY, int scrollRangeX,
            int scrollRangeY, int maxOverScrollX, int maxOverScrollY, boolean isTouchEvent) {

        final boolean returnValue = super.overScrollBy(deltaX, deltaY, scrollX, scrollY, scrollRangeX,
                scrollRangeY, maxOverScrollX, maxOverScrollY, isTouchEvent);

        // Does all of the hard work...
        OverscrollHelper.overScrollBy(PullToRefreshListView.this, deltaY, scrollY, isTouchEvent);

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

How to fix this bug in consideration of that I can't to reproduce it? May be it is possible to suppress it?

Comment: I'm also having this problem, did you find any solution to it?

Comment: No, I didn't find any solution yet...

Comment: I solved my issue, my problem was caused because I called "notifyDataSetChanged" too often in short intervals.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But... My application is a chat and I need to call notifyDataSetChanged() often.

Comment: Yeah, but how often do you call it? I have also implemented a chat in my application (this was not where it crashed though). But can you post some code where this crash occur?

Comment: There is too much code needed for understanding... And I can't pubish it all, sorry. But you are right, in my application it can be called two times simultaneously, when message come from two different sources (HTTP and socket). I will prevent this behaviour. Thank you for help!

Comment: @BArtWell You may want to answer your own question and accept it. This helps future viewers and also marks this question as resolved. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for late answer. Yes, I want to confirm @Carnal's comment. I limit calls of notifyDataSetChanged() and this exception doesn't more thrown.