# Chrisbane PullToRefreshListView IllegalStateException

Tags: android, pull-to-refresh

I had to implement iOS like pull to refresh list in my Android app. I decided to go for [this library](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh). It's pull to refresh performance is awesome. But I'm facing one random exception which leads to app crash. It happens sometime that `IllegalStateException` is thrown pointing to this line in `PullToRefreshListView.java` in `InternalListView` class code.

```
return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
```

I'm unable to understand this issue. Can any body guide me to solve this issue please.

Comment: plese put some code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I was missing `notifyDataSetChanged()` in one of the callbacks. Adding resolved the issue. Thanks everyone who spared time to reply to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Please check, you might be calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` too often in short intervals. 
You can go through this link.[Chrisbane PullToRefreshListView IllegalStateException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19077626/illegalstateexception-in-pulltorefreshlistviewinternallistviewsdk9)